# CSS Partial selectors with nth-of-type

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to select elements in CSS using partial selector and nth-child

```
[id^='selectID']:nth-of-type(even) {
 color: red;
 display block;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

But I want to select the items as odd child or even children

- selectID1 --> should get the class
- selectID2 --> shouldn't get the class
- selectID3 --> should get the class
- selectID4 --> shouldn't get the class

Comment: Your title says `nth-of-child`. No such selector exists in CSS. In your introductory text you say *using partial selector and `nth-child`* (there is no such thing as a partial selector, did you mean attribute selector?). In your code then, it's suddenly `:nth-of-type(even)`. Are you sure you know what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-of-type` does not care about anything other than element type and all it can ask is:

**"Am I the nth element of my type in my parent element?"**

What you want cannot currently be achieved using CSS unless all the elements in question are **siblings** (that is, share the same parent element).

So in this scenario your selector would work:

```
<div>
   <div id="selectID1"></div>
   <p>Test</p>
   <div id="selectID2"></div>
   <div id="selectID3"></div>
   <div id="selectID4"></div>
</div>
```

In this (and many other) scenarios it wouldn't work the way you want:

```
<section>
   <div id="selectID1"></div>
</section>
<section>
   <p>Test</p>
   <div id="selectID2"></div>
</section>
<div id="selectID3"></div>
<div id="selectID4"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parent element a `ul` and all children `li` and you will be able to use :nth-child(). This way you can easily pick which one to style.

Example:

1 2 3 4

`ul:nth-child(even) li` - will pick 2 and 4;

```
 ul:nth-child(2) li,
 ul:nth-child(4) li - will do the same.
```

Hope that helps.